# Python variable not carrying through to urllib

Tags: python, urllib

I'm scraping a csv file from an opendata site and I want to use the file's URL as the name of the file, but when I add a prefix to the string to ensure that the full url is put into the filename. However, the amended variable doesn't get replicated by urllib and file is saved without the prefix.

When I print the variable just before using urllib, I get the full variable including the prefix, so I know that my 'replace' line is working.

Here's my code, can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

```
# add the right prefix onto the url
csvUrl = csvUrl.replace("/government","http://www.gov.uk/government")
print csvUrl

# check that the file hasn't already been downloaded
if csvUrl in fileList:
    print "found this file already: "+ csvUrl
else:
    # Download the file
    urllib.urlretrieve(csvUrl, os.path.basename(csvUrl))
    print "saving: "+ csvUrl
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`os.path.basename(/foo/http://www.gov.uk/government)` will return `government` because, well, that's the base name. `basename` assumes that you are giving it a path to a file, not a filename containing `/` characters.

```
>>> csvUrl = 'foo/government'
>>> csvUrl = csvUrl.replace("/government","http://www.gov.uk/government")
>>> csvUrl
'foohttp://www.gov.uk/government'
>>> os.path.basename(csvUrl)
'government'
```

In addition, why are you trying to put `/` into a filename? In which operating system does this work? I'm pretty sure you can't, and you really don't want to.

Comment: Thanks, that makes perfect sense. I'm using the url as a filename to provide an audit trail for the file, but I've realised that's not such a good idea, I guess it was to save opening up the csv and writing the source url into a new column in each file.